# Is the state of a system invariant or not?

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, observers, invariants

In a physics textbook by Eric Mazur there is the following phrase:

> *“The state of any object or system cannot depend on the motion of the observer.”*

Here, the state is understood as some complete set of physical parameters of the system: shape, temperature, … In the textbook this statement is used both in the Galilean relativity and special relatively to argue that some physical quantity is invariant.

I have 2 questions on this.

1. To me, the statement that “the system’s state is invariant” (which means that any attribute of a system or an object should be invariant: shape, size, inertia, mass, charge, temperature, …) intuitively makes sense, but how can one prove that?
2. If this statement is true, why does it fail for inertia and length of an object, which moves at relativistic speed relative to observer (special relatively)? Inertia and length are obviously attributes of a system, thus should be invariant (like charge and temperature).

Answer (score 2):

The state of a system is an invariant in the sense that any *well-defined* experiment should yield the same result regardless of the observer. However, it is extremely common to mistake what is a well-defined experiment.

Asking what is the length of an object, or it's energy, are not well-defined experiments, because these terms have different meanings for different observers. What an observer calls "energy", another calls "a specific linear combination of the object's energy and momentum". Nevertheless, if you specify your experiment by actually giving an experimental prescription, there is no ambiguity. Different observers might interpret the result differently (one of them calls it energy, the other calls it something else), but the result is the same.

As for proving this, I'd say it is a logical necessity. Pick an arbitrary experiment. Now couple a bomb to it such that, if the result is above a certain value, the bomb goes off and kills the experimenter. Now, all observers must agree on whether the experimenter died due to the bomb or not. Hence, all observers must agree on the result of the experiment. Otherwise, changing observers would change reality itself.

Of course, different observers might give different names to the quantity being measured. One of them calls it energy, another calls it a linear combination of energy and momentum, etc. However, this just shows that our words are often poorly chosen, leading us to think an experiment is well-defined when it isn't.

As a further example, suppose two different observers try to measure the energy of some particle (each of them according to their own notion of "energy"). These are different experiments, because you have to use different apparatuses or couple them differently to the particle. Hence, asking to measure the energy of a particle is not a well-defined experiment, since each choice of observer leads to a different experiment.

Comment: I understand you about observers using different definitions of quantities that they are going to measure in the same experiment. Though, asking my question I assumed that observers use the same definitions and I wondered whether they could see different  **values** of the same physical quantities, (quantities describing the state of the system, not motion). Mazur says “they can’t, because the state doesn’t depend on the motion of the observer”.

Comment: I guess you answered my 1st question, though I feel like I have to think about it thoroughly, especially about “Otherwise, changing observers would change reality itself.”
But what can you say about my second question, i.e. what would you say about phenomena of raise of inertia and length contraction noticeable in special relativity in context of statement that “the state is invariant”. As I see, these phenomena don’t correspond to the statement, cos inertia and length seem to be intrinsic properties of a system/object.

Comment: @Alexandr "asking my question I assumed that observers use the same definitions" this is a wrong assumption. Length is defined differently by different observers. Suppose you were to measure the length of a rod. An observer defines length as what you see when you put a ruler side by side with the rod, at rest. A second observer, moving relative to the rod, defines length to be what you see when a ruler passes by the rod at some prescribed speed. These are different experiments. There's no reason to expect them to give the same result. We call both quantities "length", but they are different.

Comment: @Alexandr "Inertia and length seem to be intrinsic properties of a system/object" I'm not sure what you mean by "inertia is an in intrinsic property of a system". Whether the system is moving inertially is surely an intrinsic property, and all observers will agree on it. However, length is not. *Proper length* of an object is an intrinsic property, but length itself is not, since you need to *choose* an experiment to measure length, and different choices yield different results. For example, whether you pick the ruler to be at rest or not.

Comment: While the state is invariant, what one calls "length" is not. This is the origin of the apparent paradox.

Comment: I feel like I didn’t get easy answers I look for, but instead I have now new questions, which are to be formulate later (mb in new page-questions here). Anyway, thanks for all your comments, that gave me food for thought.

Comment: If you don’t object, I would go on asking you on this subject.
Would it be correct if I say the following: «The state of an object is a set of physical quantities that can be measured at rest with this object.»
If it is true, we can make 2 conclusions.

Comment: 1. Inertia is not a quantity of state, because it can be measured only when the object is moving (We have to measure acceleration of the object and forces action on it). Consequently, inertia of an object is a characteristic of both the object and the observer.

Comment: 2. Length is a quantity of state. The length contraction, which is noticeable in special relativity, occurs not because the object changes (i.e. its state changes) but because the space itself changes (contracts) for an observer who moves very fast. Nonetheless, because the «length» is still different for different observers the «proper length» is really quantity of state, but not just «length».

Comment: @Alexandr Feel free to ask as much as you'd like =). As for "The state of an object is a set of physical quantities that can be measured at rest with this object", this is incorrect. One can perfectly well determine the state of a system at other reference frames. The state is a set of data capable of completely determining the system (this is a bit more subtle in quantum theories).

Comment: Chapter 1 of the book "Mathematical Theory of Quantum Fields", by H. Araki, has a great discussion on what are observables and states. I really recommend taking a look at it.

Comment: Shortly, Araki will define a state as an equivalence class of "preparations of a system". A preparation here means the intuitive meaning: how you prepare your system. Two preparations are said to be equivalent if they yield the same results for every possible experiment you conduct. Notice that nowhere in this definition one needs to give any information about observers.

Comment: “Feel free to ask as much as you'd like” – this is kind of you. Btw, Happy New Year! 
Unfortunately, I didn’t find that book in the internet to check that up. But for now let me not use terms such as “preparation” and return to what I said above to clarify some things.

Comment: Eric Mazur in his textbook often separates two concepts: «state» and «motion» like in the following sentence: “Collisions that changes either the motion or the state of the object …” (page 123. 1st global edition). However, in the same book he sometimes uses a phrase “a state of motion”. Anyway, in my opinion, this separation is very reasonable, because the motion (of the whole system) is a relative thing, while the state is not (which is I am trying to prove here, or find a good proof). I used this idea when tried to formulate the definition of «state» above.

Comment: Let me another try. But lets stick to non-quantum physics. As I understand, the problem of quantum physics is that when we try to determine the state of the micro-object, we inevitably change that state, and so concept “state“ here became more complicated. Meanwhile, in macrolevel, we can assume that we are able to make our measures so that they don’t influence the object’s state.

Comment: So, …. This time I would say the following. The state of an object/system is a set of physical quantities that fully determines this object/system as a part of reality. The reality is what exists objectively; thus, the state cannot depend on an observer and their motion.

Comment: Motion is a relative thing. Consequently, any physical quantity that depends on motion of an object (and thus of an observer) or is defined for an object moving only (otherwise it always gives zero value of an object at rest), is not invariant.

Comment: As I a consequence, physical quantities of state (length or proper length, total mass, total internal energy, …)  can be measured for an object/system that is either at rest or moving as a whole, while quantities of motion (velocity of center mass, total inertia, total momentum, total kinetic energy, …) can be measured or make sense (i.e. give nonzero value) only when that object/system is moving, but not at rest.

Comment: Sorry for plenty of text (I know, this is not supposed to be in comments), but I would be grateful if you could comment on all of this above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141676/discussion-between-nickolas-alves-and-alexandr).